# Autofilling until the last row

Tags: vba, excel

I have been autofilling a report that is using a range that is Q10:Q57. However, I realized that since it is run daily, there is a high chance that the ranges will be higher or lower. I currently have

```
Range("Q10").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q10:Q57"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("Q10:Q57").Select
Calculate
```

Is there a way to autofill until the last row instead of Q57? I was thinking of maybe using excel down? What are your thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Try the property UsedRange

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to find the last row:

```
Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal rngToCheck As Excel.Range) As Long

Dim rngLast As Excel.Range

rngLast = rngToCheck.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious)

    If rngLast Is Nothing Then
        GetLastRow = rngToCheck.Rows.Count
    Else
        GetLastRow = rngLast.Rows.Count
    End If

End Function
```

Now create a procedure that calls the function

```
Sub findAndFillLastRow()

  Dim yourSheet As Excel.Worksheet

   With yourSheet
        lngLr = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows).Row

        .Range("Q10:Q").AutoFill(.Range("Q10:Q" & lngLr), Excel.XlAutoFillType.xlFillDefault)

    End With

End Sub
```

That shoud work.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
Dim rng_AutoFill As Range
Set rng_AutoFill = Range( _
                    Range("Q10"), _
                    Range("Q1000000").End(xlUp))
Range("Q10").AutoFill _
    Destination:=rng_AutoFill, _
    Type:=xlFillDefault
Calculate
```